# Space below absolute positioned div at bottom of page

Tags: css, html

I attempting to add a 'margin' below an absolutely positioned div which is placed at the complete bottom of the page.

I have tried two methods sofar.

Firstly, I have attempted to add:

```
body {
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

However, this did nothing, due to the div being absolutely positioned and as such, not being affected by the padding.

I also attempted to use the following method:

```
#formwrap {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

This also did not work, because the div is placed at the bottom of the page and has nothing to space itself from (perhaps I am wrong in saying that- but it did not work nonetheless).

Is there any other working method to create space between the div and the bottom of the page?

Cheers.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="formwrap">
<p>______________________________________________________________________</p>
<p>Welcome to Engage Arcade, an arcade gaming website developed by Engage Entertainment.</p>
<p>______________________________________________________________________</p> 

<br/>

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fengagearcade&amp;width=490&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=435" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:396px; background: white; float:left; " allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

</div>
```

(the iframe has nothing to do with the issue- I have the same formwrap div on every page, and every page has the same issue).

Here is the CSS:

```
#formwrap {
 width: 700px;
 opacity:0.8;
 z-index:2;
 font: 15px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:-350px;
 left:50%;
 top:300px;
 border-radius:10px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:white;
 border-width:2px;
 overflow:auto;
 background-color:#000;
 padding:7px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba (255,255,0,0.9);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried padding-bottom for formwrap?

Comment: post your html please

Comment: I did try padding-bottom for formwrap Huangism, although padding only increases the div itself from the last piece of content inside of the div. 

Here is the HTML Banana:

Comment: Update the question with the html, don't put it in comment

Comment: Hiding. Will put in question.

Comment: @user3227878 you said this div is the last thing on the page. If you just pad the bottom of that div it will give you space at the bottom of the page. What's the issue?

Comment: If I pad the bottom of that div, all it does is increase the size of the div, it does not create space between the div and the bottom of the page.

Comment: @user3227878 what's the difference if it's the last item on the page? space is space. Try bottom: 30px on the div then, make top: auto. Also pad the bottom of the body the same amount of the bottom attribute

Comment: The div has background-color along with borders, I am trying to push make space between the bottom of the div (where the border is) and the bottom of the page, because I have a small 25px footer at the bottom of my page.

Comment: So you want this div to rest above the footer... then why not just place it before the footer instead of positioning it absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Add margin bottom to body and define bottom value for the absolute div same as body bottom margin.

Comment: Unfortunately this had no effect. To clarify, you were saying to add margin-bottom:30px; to both body and the div?

Comment: He is saying, add margin-bottom to the body and add `bottom` to the formwrap. But you have a `top` set for formwrap, so you need to make that `top:auto` and `bottom:30px`

Comment: I see, some of it is just passing right over me sorry- I have been coding all day. This is not exactly what I'm looking for. Perhaps it would be easier if showed you the website in question?

Comment: Yes, or make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It's still not entirely clear what you're after.

Comment: I will use this page on my website as an example.

http://terms.engagearcade.com/

As you see, the div is the main content div. If you scroll to the bottom of the page, the end of the div is underneath the footer. How can I make it appear above the footer?

Comment: I'm not sure why the absolute positioning is necessary. I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WPZ7m/) that shows it's easy to do what you want by not positioning the div absolutely. Al it needs is a bottom margin that is at least as large as the height of the footer.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the <main> </main> is however, the div in question 'is' the main content- the div needs to start at 300px from the top and extend for as long as the content goes.

Comment: The `<main>` I wrote that because you had `position:absolute` and `top:300px` for the div, so I needed something above the div to make it end up 300px from the top! Sorry if I made it a `main`, I could have made it a `header`.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand! I'll test it out. Sorry for the slowness to understand. I am still somewhat new to coding and while I understand most, certain things are still confusing to me.

Comment: Adding the <main> </main> did not work entirely as I hoped, however by adding 13 break points I was able to achieve the desired effect. Thanks a heap for your help! It's not exactly perfect code with that many break points haha, but it does the job!

Comment: Then define the height instead of breaks.

Comment: @user3227878 By the way, it's not called a break point, it's a line break. (And the difference is important, because we do have things called breakpoints in CSS, so this could be confusing.)